# sql IN query questions

Tags: mysql

I want to find the "id" of each row in my sql table column "teams" = "11"

However, "teams" is stored in this format:

1,2,3,4,5,11,20

1

1,3,4

11,34

I have tried using the "in" query, but will not work.

```
$query = "SELECT u_id FROM #__bl_teamcord WHERE (11 IN (teams))";       
             $db->setQuery($query);
    $remail = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: See [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns).

Comment: That book cover cracks me up..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT u_id FROM #__bl_teamcord WHERE FIND_IN_SET('11',teams)
```

However, if these tables have a lot of data or performance is critical, you might want to consider normalizing your data into a separate table rather than using a comma delimited list in each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it efficiently, but if you insist use regexp. I would advice joining against a teams table where each team is a row.